# Back button after login in Android (Re-enter issue)

Tags: android, facebook, authentication, back-button

I'm writing my app that contains login facebook function.

As this moment, my app can jump to another fragment(post-login page) after logging-in
And I use finish(); after startActivity(intent); to avoid users going back to login page if they logged-in successfully.

However, I am facing a new problem.
If I try to press back key in post-login page, it will go back to the main menu of Android. Sounds good. But when I try to open my app again, it starts my login page again with a logout button. After 2 secs, it jumps to my post login page.

Is there any way to prevent this?
I hope my app can open the post-login page directly after I try to restart my app if the user logged-in successfully before.

Cheers~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a boolean `isLoggedIn` in `Shared Preferences` after you login default initial value being `false`.

If login was succesfull update `isLoggedIn` to `true`.

Now when app restarts check the value of `isLoggedIn`.

If `isLoggedIn` value is `true`, start post login Activity else start login Activity.

Comment: thank you for your reply.
I'm wondering where the "if" statement should place in. OnCreate?
i tried to do this in OnCreate before, but it crashed. It should be something wrong in my code.

Comment: Try using a `splashActivity` in your app as the first activity. Use it to determine the login status and which activity to go to.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can do this, you could just create a File into this path (after User logged in):

```
context.getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath()
```

After you created - just check at Start of the Application if the file is on Users device, and link it to your MainMenu.

If you did successfully save the File in this Path (you prevent after a User deinstalls and reinstalls the app from not loggin in anymore. (This workflow is also used in Whatsapp, if you delete Data, you got to log in again -for example if somebody sells his smartphone to an other user, who reinstalls exactly this app, the file will be automatically deleted, so he got to log in or even sign up again)

```
public class InstallCertificate {

    private Context context = null;
    private File certificate = null;

    public InstallCertificate(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void createCertificateAtVerifying() {
        try {

            certificate = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(null)
                    .getAbsolutePath(), "InstallationCertificate");
            certificate.createNewFile();
            System.out
                    .println("successfully installed Certificate on cell phone");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public boolean checkIfCertificateIsInstalled() {
        boolean certificateExists = false;
        certificate = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(null)
                .getAbsolutePath(), "InstallationCertificate");

        if (certificate.exists()) {
            return true;
        }
        return certificateExists;
    }
```

Comment: glad to hear this new method!
So, I need to create a new object of InstallCertificate and called createCertificateAtVerifying() after the user had logged-in successfully? And call checkIfCertificateIsInstalled() in OnCreate of my Login Activity??

Comment: yes thats right, its no new method at all - but its a common workflow for most android apps :)